# Null check operator used on a null value flutter in stream builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Stream Builder to check wether the user has logged in or not it was working just fine but all of a sudden its giving the error

```
 `return StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Scaffold(
          //backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF686B),
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              centerTitle: true,
              title: const Text("CHAT APP"),
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child:

        );
      } else {
        return homepage(url: auth,);
      }
    });`
```

Comment: can you point the use case of `!`, i think this snippet isnt enough

Comment: i and checking whether the snapshot has data or not if does not have the data show scafold else show homepage

Comment: perhaps the issue lies inside `homepage`